# How do I read files with a01 extension

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I have read a lot about opening up files with .axx extension, but I had no success.
Fox Pro, renaming gave garbled result, hence I came here.

My requirement - I need to read database tables inside these .a01 files using Python, so that I could extract the updated data.

Any hint or suggestion as to how should I read the file with my own eyes( I have never seen any files of these kinds before). Many thanks.

Edit - I tried ARJ32, it gave an error "file is not an ARJ archive". Winrar too gives an error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @olinox14: Thank you very much for the reply. I have edited the question.